# Add a number to the beginning of every-line in a .lst file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, random

So I used "shuf" to make a word-list, The problem is when I run the command
 `shuf -i 0500000000-0599999999 -o passwords.lst`
 it doesn't type the first number which is '0' so I want a command to type that '0' into the beginning of every-line, if it's not possible with shuf any command will help.

Comment: This is not a programming question, so stackoverflow is the wrong site. Every question on this site requires source code.

Comment: Isn't that a very restrictive interpretation of source code? The boundaries between calling a command from the command line on the one hand and writing a small script on the other hand are pretty fluent, aren't they? :-) Which site would you recommend? SuperUser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piped command will simply prepend a zero:

```
shuf -i 0500000000-0599999999|sed s/^/0/ > passwords.lst
```